# OutOfMemoryError: pittest mutation testing

Tags: java, mutation-testing, pitest

I want to generate a mutation testing report for my module (I have 225 classes in my module) using pitest.

I've added the needed dependencies and configured the plugin. The problem is when I run the maven goal `mvn org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage` for the whole module I get an `OutOfMemorryError`.
I don't think there are any memory issues with our tests because things are working as expected when I run all module tests.

Note that I was able to generate it for a single package but not for the whole module.

I tried to increase the memory used by surefire plugin using this configuration:

```xml
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Now when I run the plugin goal `mvn org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage` **for the whole module** the execution hangs forever, as you can see it took me **13h 45 min** with no result:

[image]

I had to force stop it because the execution is extremely slow and isn't going anywhere.

Why does it hang forever?

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: How long does your test suite take normally? Mutation testing can take several orders of magnitude longer, and takes a lot more resources than your tests normally would. Have you tried using more RAM? 1024m would probably be adequate for a normal test suite but isn't exactly much for mutation testing. Also: code complexity and lines of code are a much higher factor here than number of classes

Comment: Test suites in the concerned module take about 20-30 min to run. I have 8 GB of ram in my virtual machine (Corpo VM). How much ram do you propose I should try for mutation testing?

Comment: If the normal tests take 20-30 minutes then it's not surprising that the mutation testing takes this long. I would suggest starting with 4GB. If the tests don't go out of memory then you can try a lower amount

Comment: Using `<configuration><argLine>-Xmx4096m</argLine></configuration>` on surefire plugin. I got `Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "PIT Stream Monitor"`

Comment: 20 minutes is a very long time to test such a small project. I suspect you may integration tests rather than unit tests, in which case the project is not sutiable for mutation testing.

Comment: You might want to look at https://pitest.groupcdg.com/docs/basic-maven-setup.html#first-run and try the CLASSLIMIT feature to see how the run goes with fewer mutations.